# Use a custom function to sort an asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

Here's the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="MyGridView_PageIndexChanging"
    OnSorting="MyGridView_Sorting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here, the Id column is a string consisting always of the letter "T" followed by a number, i.e. "T1" or "T597"  The other columns are fairly ordinary name and description String fields.

I need this Id column to sort as though the Id were numeric, ignoring the letter in front.  But because it is there, it is being treated as a String and sorting as such: T1, T10, T100, T2, T231, T34, ...

So what I thought would be possible is:

```
protected void MyGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SortExpression.Equals("Id")
    {
         // Special sorting code
    }
    else
    {
        // Normal sorting code
    }
}
```

Where the "normal" sorting code follows the common pattern of converting the `DataSource` to `DataView` and setting `DataView.Sort = e.SortExpression` etc, for example: [allow sorting by column gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776372/allow-sorting-by-column-gridview)

So what do I do for the "special" sorting code?

UPDATE:  Just to be clear, I have no trouble rolling my own function to compare two strings as I need.  I do not, however, know how to *apply* that function to my Data Grid/ Data Source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridView` allows `DataKeyNames`, and that is the solution here.  When setting up the Data Source (in my case, a SQL query) include both the "FullId" and a "PlainId" which has stripped off the leading character and parsed the remainder as int.  Use "FullId" as the column's text value, but make "PlainId" one of the `DataKeyNames` and use that as the `SortExpression` for the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the IComparer class for the DataGridView.Sort:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can separate the "T" and the following number in the Compare method.