# How to sort depends on Particular Column In Datagridview?

Tags: c#-4.0

if grid like this

```
     Name     Age

     Raj      20
     Biny     19
     Raj      17
     Jose     27
     Jose     15
```

now am click Name Grid Column Means

I want output like below

```
       Name     Age

      Biny     19        
      Jose     15
      Jose     27
      Raj      17
      Raj      20

 See above table sort Based on Name column
```

Eg:-
now jose age also sort like 15,27

am using below code but it does'nt work properly
 private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)

{
            var sortGlyph = dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;

```
        switch (sortGlyph)
        {
            case SortOrder.None:
            case SortOrder.Ascending:
                     dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Name"], ListSortDirection.Descending);

                dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
                break;
            case SortOrder.Descending:
                                   dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Name"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
                break;
        }
```

}

Below Code is Answer For Above Question

```
       switch (sortGlyph)
        {
            case SortOrder.None:
            case SortOrder.Ascending:
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Name,Age";
                dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection     =SortOrder.Descending;
                break;
            case SortOrder.Descending:
                                    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Name,Age";
                                    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
                                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                                    dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything? Btw, are you using ASP.NET or Winforms?

Comment: am using win forms only

Comment: before you bind the source can you sort the column it will may resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about doing it in conjunction with paging, there's no simple and scalable solution. In fact, that is kind of a holy grail of business application web development. See, for example, the StackOverflow question [Dynamic Sorting within SQL Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149380/dynamic-sorting-within-sql-stored-procedures), which concerns the same thing. After all, if we had dynamic sorting on our database servers, we would only have to code the mechanism for managing the user's sort choices.

You really only have three options for multi-column sorts:

- Do it in the client, letting your data container do the heavy lifting (when you're using a data container that has this functionality built in, like [`System.Data.DataView`][2]).
- Write your own algorithm and sort the data yourself before binding.
- Do it at the database server via one of the solutions discussed in the link above.

Neither of the client-side solutions are really scalable since they involve pulling and delivering all your data when you may only need a subset.

Comment: finally i got answer for above question

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples you can find,

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/12/aspnet-gridview-sorting-example-how-to.html

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.in/2012/06/sorting-gridview-columns-headers-aspnet.html

[allow sorting by column gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776372/allow-sorting-by-column-gridview)

Comment: i Think there is inbuilt option, only have to allow sorting, will have to check, mean while u can look it, i think it should have

Comment: Yes go to column collection select the column, there is sort mode in right panel, :)